# When does GetTickCount() start counting?

Tags: c++, winapi, counter

I am read the documentation for [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and am wondering whether it begins counting from when the system is powered on or last rebooted?

**In other words, is the timer reset to 0 when the computer is restarted?**

Comment: What is the difference between powered on and rebooted?

Comment: It starts at zero at a full boot, not at a restore from sleep or hibernation.  Not caring about this is important, not in the least because this behavior isn't promised anywhere.

Comment: @sarnold: If you don't want to answer then don't. Obviously there's a difference in my case.

Comment: GetTickCount can roll over, don't use it for long-running events. And being rude to people trying to help you guarantees no one will answer your question.

Comment: I think sarnold was asking for a reasonable clarification; not least because a reboot does power-cycle the machine, making it unclear what you might have expected the difference to be.

Comment: @ahmd0 : sarnold's question is extremely pertinent; the fact that _you_ don't recognize it as such does not warrant rudeness, especially if you expect anyone to help you after observing your attitude. I'll rephrase his question for you: "What is _your perceived_ difference between powered on and rebooted?"

Comment: @Hans Passant: So, you're saying it's a reboot, right? Not a shut-down.

Comment: That's a nonsensical distinction; what's the difference between a shutdown followed by a power-on vs. a reboot?

Comment: @ahmd0, it's important here not to be rude to people you're asking for free help. :) Asking for more information or clarification isn't "not wanting to answer". Please try and be polite. (And there is absolutely no difference between a shutdown and a reboot; a reboot is a shutdown with a restart to the OS. The difference is only meaningful to the BIOS and hardware.)

Comment: The problem is that nobody has yet figured out what the value is while the machine is shut down.

Comment: You don't power on an OS.  You power on a physical piece of hardware.  Anyway, it should be pretty trivial to test whether `GetTickCount` returns a value indicating when Windows was started and when the hardware was powered on.

Comment: The difference between a machine having been shut-down vs. rebooted is that a shut-down can be followed by a power-off, when reboot does not. Still, why does it matter what I need this for? Obviously I do. Otherwise I'd not ask it here. Is it also worth going into all this polemic vs. simply answering the question? And to sarnold's question -- my answer was to the way he worded it when I read it.

Comment: "*a shut-down can be followed by a power-off*" Huh? How can a shutdown _not_ be followed by a power-off? "*when reboot does not*" According to whom? "*Still, why does it matter what I need this for?*" It doesn't -- nobody asked that to begin with. "*Is it also worth going into all this polemic vs. simply answering the question?*" Yes, because your question is nonsensical, and we need to make sense of it in order to answer it. Come back when you learn how to ask a proper question, or at least learn how to not be rude to people trying to help you.

Comment: @ildjarn: What is not clear in my question? You reboot computer and it simply reloads OS -- the power is not turned off. When someone shuts it down, the power can be switched off (or computer can be powered off.) I want to know if rebooting a computer resets the tick counter. How else do you want me to word it to skip all this BS?

Comment: "*You reboot computer and it simply reloads OS -- the power is not turned off.*" According to _whom_? _Why_ do you think this? We're back to _your perceptions_ here, which you have yet to adequately explain.

Comment: I hope my edit clarifies things?

Comment: @muntoo : Until someone describes the perceived difference (to the OS) between 'rebooting' and 'restarting' and 'shutting down then powering on', I doubt it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebooting_(computing)#Soft_reboot

Comment: And, BTW, I am pretty sure this can be empirically tested.

Comment: @muntoo : Again (regarding soft reboots), what is the difference to the OS, which is what's being queried here?

Comment: @ildjarn Based on the answer below... nothing.

Comment: @muntoo : Exactly my point. ;-]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Wow, so much pointless rhetoric. I should've gone the route of testing it out myself instead of asking here. Thanks, muntoo, for rephrasing it. For those who's interested to know, here's the result of my actual test:

- Shutting down the system and then restarting it, obviously resets the tick counter returned by GetTickCount or GetTickCount64 APIs.
- Rebooting (or restarting) a Windows OS **also resets** those counters. (And that is what I needed to know.)

PS. This question **is not** about the difference between rebooting and shutdown, nor which API is better to use.

Comment: Yes, Hans Passant already [gave you that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308588/when-does-gettickcount-start-counting#comment13268178_10308588)

Comment: His answer, the way he formulated it, is more misleading than helpful...